# Different multiple frontend projects (different url) use same admin portal

Tags: .net-core

I have few different frontend projects but they use same admin portal. Let's say

Frontend A project + Admin Portal A = port 9000

Frontend B project + Admin Portal A = port 9001

Frontend C project + Admin Portal A = port 9002

Instead of creating admin portal in each frontend project, how to create SINGLE admin portal in 1 project that all frontend projects can use?

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: "is it possible?"  "yes"  "how?"  "you just have to do it really" - currently this question does not lead to very interesting answers, there is not enough detail to work with.

Comment: Presumably the admin portal is itself a frontend that talks to a backend. Can you make a frontend that talks to multiple backends and either merges the information or lets you select which backend to use? Yeah, sure...